# Show Pop Up panel/window in Ext JS Framework

Tags: extjs

I have this form and I want to populate a new window when I click a given button. Anyone who can help?

I tried creating a new panel and attaching it to a constructor but this is not working. If a reference to solving this issue will be appreciated.

Comment: Do you just want a window? e.g. Ext.window.Window? Or what do you want exactly? If you create a sencha fiddle i can surely help you

Comment: I want window with an image data

Comment: Then I can lender that window panel to a button so when one click that button gets window with image displayed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to create a window you can simply use the [Ext.window.Window](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.window.Window.html).

And if you try to show an image you can use [Ext.Image](https://docs.sencha.com/extjs/7.6.0/classic/Ext.Img.html).

Here is an example:

```
Ext.create('Ext.window.Window', {
    title: 'Hello',
    itemId: 'window-image',
    height: 500,
    width: 350,
    bodyPadding: 5,
    layout: 'fit',
    items: [{
        xtype: 'image',
        src: 'https://www.w3schools.com/tags/img_girl.jpg'

    }]
}).show();
```

And here is a sencha fiddle: [example](https://fiddle.sencha.com/#view/editor&fiddle/3mav)

Comment: And to i lender it in a button ?

Comment: Did you look into the example?